# Is it possible to get common difference from the output of floor function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am currently running a web scraping program and seeing the time number constantly showing up on my screen. Then suddenly I have a question as the title says.

To specify,

Given $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ an arithmetic series and $b_i = \lfloor a_i\rfloor$ ($b_i$ is the biggest integer that is not larger than $a_i$). Is it possible to get the common difference $d = a_{i+1} - a_i$ ONLY from series $\{b_i\}$?

Comment: You can in a limiting sense, you will have $d = \lim_{k \to \infty} {\lfloor a_k \rfloor \over k}$.

Comment: Wow, that is what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\fr{\operatorname{frac}}$
Here’s the proof: As $a_k = a_0 + kd$ and setting $\fr x = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ (which always is in $[0..1)$),
$$\frac {\lfloor a_k \rfloor} k = \frac {a_k - \fr a_k} k = d + \frac{a_0 + \fr a_k} k \overset{k → ∞}\longrightarrow d.$$

Comment: Thanks! That is really helpful!